# Starting a while loop (game update loop) at the end of onCreate & listen to any onClick events

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, while-loop, oncreate

I've searched over and over and couldn't find anything that I may be able to use. Maybe my keywords are wrong but I'm trying to do a turn-based multiplayer game on Android and the Activity that the battle is occuring will run a battleLoop() function at the end of onCreate.

This battleLoop will do something like this:

1. (While playerHP >= 0 || opponentHP >= 0), do steps 2-6
2. Retrieve who's turn it is from database
3. If it's player's turn, then allow for player to tap attack or defend button. While it's the player's turn, do nothing **UNTIL** player inserts an action. Then keep this information to send to database.
4. If not player's turn, then keep on checking who's turn is it.
5. When both done, calculate, apply and update DB
6. CheckWin (To see who won)

The problem is with the while loop. I can't figure out a way to start this function battleLoop() **AFTER** onCreate is finished. I want this function to work similar to the Update() function in game engines such as Unity where the function will be executed after onCreate is finished executed.

Things I tried:

1. Function call at the end of onCreate
2. Threads & system.sleep (to allow for pausing while player inputs an action)

Comment: There are tons and tons of tutorials out there about Android game development. Most of them involve creating a game loop using a `SurfaceView` or a similar setup. For example, this set of tutorials goes quite in depth on how to do what you are trying to achieve: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-basic-game_05.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If my game does not rely heavily on animation or drawing of the sprites, (I really just need the game loop) is these methods still the way to go?

Comment: If your game is turn based and doesn't involve a lot of animation, then there's a chance you don't even need a game loop to begin with. Instead, you would just perform the checks you mentioned when a user takes an action instead. All of the steps you mentioned above don't require a loop. You would just trigger them based on what's happening in the game. For example, get who's turn it is, now based on result start player turn, based on player turn check HP, etc.

Comment: But how exactly can I do this? I should call the battle function at the end of onCreate, then do corresponding checks based on previous results. Then naturally I would need to call the same function again at the end of it right? I'm having problems imagining the flow of it.

Comment: I see it happening this way: 1. `onCreate()` finishes setting up the match. 2. At the end of onCreate you fire a method to see who gets first turn. 3. It determines it's player 1's turn, so show the appropriate UI for them to make their attack, and also make other checks like HP checks, attack cooldowns, etc. 4. Show player 1 his attack UI and available attacks. 5. Player 1 makes his play. 6. Server is contacted to send play to Player 2. 7. Repeat process for player 2. Basically, something similar to that.